# Adding a space between two database fields in an angularjs table

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to put a space between two database values that are in the same column of my table, but I keep getting errors.

The rows for my table are created in my controller like this:

```
private createRow() {

     if(!this.$scope.fromTransfers){
         return [
            {cols: [{title: "Name:", field: "record.Name"}, {title: "Created:", field:"record.Created"}]},
            {cols: [{title: "Total Quantity:", field: "record.TotalQuantity"}, {title: "Total Cash:", field: "record.TotalCash + record.CurrencyReference"}]},
```

I want to add a space between record.TotalCash and record.CurrencyReference, but I get errors if I try adding a space using this method
"field: "record.TotalCash" + " " + "record.CurrencyReference"

I have also tried using the html code `&nbsp;` for a space, but it also produces an error. I don't want to have to separate these two values into two columns.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

+" "+ is the correct way, to add space, what's your error ?

```js
 let data = [{
            cols: [
                {title: "Name:", field: "record.Name"}, 
                {title: "Created:", field:"record.Created"}
            ]
        }, 
        {
            cols: [
                {title: "Total Quantity:", field: "record.TotalQuantity"}, 
                {title: "Total Cash:", field:  "record.TotalCash" + " " + "record.CurrencyReference"
            }]
        }];
        
        let record = {TotalCash: 100, CurrencyReference: '123'};
        let field = `${record.TotalCash}` +" "+ `${record.CurrencyReference}`;
        console.log(field);
        console.log(data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djtuavk1/1/

Comment: Ah, have since discovered that my rows are linked to a template so had to override this by doing the following - ```{cols: [{title: "Total Quantity:", field: "record.TotalQuantity"}, {title: "Total Cash:", template: "<div>{{record.TotalCash}} {{record.CurrencyReference}}</div>"}]}``` and this fixed the error I was having (which was no values at all showing in the column). Thank you for your help! :)